# How to find the most accessed table in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We are streaming realtime data to Redshift. The bottleneck is no of table loads that can run concurrently. We at present are running more than 1000+ loads every 15mins.

But we want to reduce this number based on how frequently these tables are used by the users. Please suggest how can we get this information in Redshift.

Comment: What are you doing about `VACUUM`, if I may ask?

Comment: Not felt the need to optimise on this yet. As i have said the same in other question. thanks.

Comment: VACCUM isn't an optimization.  It *is* Redshift.  If VACUUM is not used, using Redshift makes no sense at all - Redshift allows for timely SQL on Big Data by dint of sorting tables, and VACUUM is central to sorting.  If VACUUM is not being used, tables are not sorted, and Redshift cannot offer timely SQL on Big Data - *and there is no other reason to use it*, because it is when used in that *massively* inefficient, which makes it expensive, and it comes with a large number of onerous constraints and requirements.

Comment: Why do you think aws auto vaccum does not work?

Comment: Today let me test if doing vaccum on my own increase perf. Thanks.

Comment: Reading the docs on VACUUM and checking `select "table", unsorted,vacuum_sort_benefit from svv_table_info where vacuum_sort_benefit > 0 order by 3 desc;` returns me 0 tables which will benefit from performing VACUUM SORT, there are tables with unsorted present. Let me try vacuuming them.

Comment: On clusters with any kind of reasonable workload auto vacuum runs too infequently to matter.  You accumulate unsorted blocks far more quickly than you sort them/delete them.  You can check this yourself by examining the system tables.

Comment: That column in SVV_TABLE_INFO comes from a black box.  The view references a column in a system table to which have you have no access privs.  There is *no* documentation *whatsoever* on how that value is computed.  I would advise you that it is not prudent to trust absolutely critical central components of your system design to undocumented algorithms, which are potentially regularly changing, provided by third parties.

Comment: However, the elephant in the room here is this : if your tables are unsorted, you are not using sorting, which means you have massive inefficiency, which is expensive, along with the large range of constrants and restrictions which come with Redshift, and you have all this for the sake of *no benefit whatsoever*, because you are not sorting (which is what lets you run timely queries on Big Data, which is the use-case for Redshift).  On the face of it, you should be using a normal, unsorted row-store database.

Comment: @AlokKumarSingh How are you using these tables, and what is your requirement for querying the streaming data? Do you really need the data available real-time? You could consider storing the streaming data in S3 and using a Redshift **external table** that does not require data loading into Redshift itself. Does your business use-case require all historical data to be fully available and constantly queried, or perhaps just recent streaming data? How you _use_ the data will influence the best way to _store_ the data.

Comment: @max-ganz-ii we do sort many of the tables, but we also rely on aws auto sort

Comment: @john-rotenstein need the data as close to realtime as possible(aiming for 15mins).  Requirement is real time analytics, need all historical data, queried constantly by the users or the dashboards. We have migrated 60%  already to realtime, so looking to optimize this system for better use. Realtime updates to tables are important. Not sure external table would help here. I understand Redshift is not a OLTP db so frequent short writes is not recommended. Just trying to get as close to realtime as possible.

Comment: @john-rotenstein the main bottleneck is number of tables that needs updates and not the frequency or size of batches. Even if we make the batches load every hour the problem would still be loading 400-500 tables every hour. How do you scale this in Redshift?

Comment: My question was intended to determine whether Redshift is the appropriate platform for loading and using such data. Depending upon your actual requirements, there may be a superior way to do it (such as using Redshift Spectrum). As a simple answer, however, the best way to scale activities would be to perform them in parallel (rather than sequentially) and possibly use more nodes, or different types of nodes (eg RA3). It would require testing of each option to determine your best architecture

Comment: Thanks John. I looked at spectrum docs, it says update and delete operations are not supported in Redshift external table.

Answer (score 5):

This [view](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/184c2ba7fd9d497027a831ca72e08fe09e79fd0b/src/AdminViews/v_get_tbl_scan_frequency.sql) open sourced by awslabs can be used to query the most frequently queried tables.

### Create view

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW admin.v_get_table_scan_frequency
AS
SELECT 
    database, 
    schema AS schemaname, 
    table_id, 
    "table" AS tablename, 
    size, 
    sortkey1, 
    NVL(s.num_qs,0) num_qs
FROM svv_table_info t
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
   tbl, perm_table_name,
   COUNT(DISTINCT query) num_qs
FROM
   stl_scan s
WHERE 
   s.userid > 1
   AND s.perm_table_name NOT IN ('Internal Worktable','S3')
GROUP BY 
   tbl, perm_table_name) s ON s.tbl = t.table_id
AND t."schema" NOT IN ('pg_internal')
ORDER BY 7 desc;
```

### Table

```sql
\d admin.v_get_table_scan_frequency
   Column   |  Type  | Modifiers
------------+--------+-----------
 database   | text   |
 schemaname | text   |
 table_id   | oid    |
 tablename  | text   |
 size       | bigint |
 sortkey1   | text   |
 num_qs     | bigint |
```

### Query

```sql
select * from admin.v_get_table_scan_frequency order by num_qs;
```

### Result

```sql
database | schemaname | table_id | tablename | size  | sortkey1      | num_qs
-----------------+------------+----------+------------------------------------------+-------+---------------+--------
 db      | product    | 1        | table1    |    92 | AUTO(SORTKEY) |  13448
 db      | product    | 2        | table2    |   180 | AUTO(SORTKEY) |  13389
```

Keeping a time series data of this query in Prometheus can help find rate and frequency trend over time for each table. Based on that we can decided how frequently to refresh data in Redshift.

Comment: Well, this view defines "table use" as "number of scans".  What if some tables are used very lightly, just one or two rows taken, and others are used very heavily, with many or most rows taken?

Comment: We throttle loads based on the currently active queries. Our throttling logic would now consider this to throttle tables with no activity in past 1 week more. It should be enough for us what we calculated.

Comment: Also it would give us info of un used table over time and we would keep removing them by notifying the dev to fix the config.

Comment: Mmm.  Two things.  First, the system table content is based on data volume, not number of days.  You are not necessarily going to have a week of data.  Second, you can figure out from the system tables the number of bytes read from a table, and the number of rows written, from the low-level step tables (like STL_SCAN, which you're familiar with).

Comment: Thanks. Had a plan to export this to prometheus and make this a time series metric which our redshiftloaders would query.